# I cannot access my AWS EC2 server via IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm first time to use AWS, I follow the guideline to create the EC2 server.
and setup the FTP connection, which it is something call SSH, I don't know the server stuff, but I can connect it via my FileZilla and upload folder.

But I don't know what is the address to visit my website, and I added the rule already as below,

[image: Security Groups]

[image: Server Status]

Comment: So have you tried visiting *Public DNS* url?

Comment: yes, same as IP, cannot be accessed

Answer (score 0):

Your EC2 might not be in a public VPC.
Just assigning public DNS would not help if your EC2 is in a private VPC

Check the parent VPC details

Comment: Oh, thanks Arafat!
But where can I see the setting about VPC?

Comment: Check if an internet gateway is attached to the instance's subnet. You should see this in VPC console